# ffmpeg adds unnecessary frames to output video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a series of png images which I need to convert to a video playing at 60 frames/second.

```
ffmpeg -y -i frames/%4d.png -vcodec libx264 -r 60 video.avi
```

Code above causes the video to have 60 frames per second, but it uses the same frame two or three times, effectively ending up with twice as long 25-ish fps video. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the ffmpeg parameters are position dependend. ffmpeg gives you a hint via it's help:

```
# ffmpeg -h
...
Global options (affect whole program instead of just one file:
-loglevel loglevel  set logging level
...
Per-file main options:
-f fmt              force format
...
#
```

`-r` is on of these paramaters which are specified per-file.

In order to adapt a parameter to an input file you have to write the `-r` argument *before* the corresponding `-i` argument.

So following should work for you (worked for me with mpeg4 encoder):

```
ffmpeg -y -r 60 -i frames/%4d.png -vcodec libx264 video.avi
```

You could try also, as the libx264 encoder might not adapt the frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 60 -i frames/%4d.png -vcodec libx264 -r 60 video.avi
```

Comment: Thanks. I've read that `-r` is position dependent, but never tried using it twice... I now get weird result with 162 frames dropped from the point when input files switch from `rgba` to `rgba64be`, yet frames after dropped ones are still `rgba64be` and they are completely fine...